# Log inputstream

Tags: java, logging, inputstream

Do You know any neat solution to log an InputStream, can by into file. InputStream from a Process never ends and generate some stream from time to time.
Thanks
Bartek

Comment: Can you please be specific? Are you trying to write to a log file  in order to store information when an error occurs? Please include some background information about the project if you can.

Comment: Are you looking for something like Apache `log4j`? It's a library that allows you to write data from your application to a log file. More details here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Comment: Are you trying to record STDOUT and STDIN in a file?

Comment: the bast way will be to use log4j somehow :) There is a simple bash script which periodically prints out on the screen something, lets say every 5 minutes a date+time, process never ends. Lunched by `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` then InputStream from this process needs to be stored into a file

Comment: From 1.7 on, if you are using ProcessBuilder you can redirect IO Streams easily using ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().  [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki)

Comment: this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434699

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log never-ending stream transparently - I believe you need a Tee filter - see answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043634/is-there-a-simple-tee-filter-for-java-streams). E.g. you can use Commons IO.

Answer (score 0):

For you case is the most sutable will be `log4j`.

But you can redirect `System.err` and `System.out` into console or smth else and it'll be write all errors in specific stream.

**upd:**

```
# Root logger option log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout  
# Direct log messages to a log file log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1 log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L
- %m%n  
# Direct log messages to stdout log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Do You have any proposal how to redirect InputStream into a file using log4j?

Comment: ok, here is system.out redirected but how to redirect different InputStream (for example Process), can be programmatically.