# scala shutdown hook when closing forcebly

Tags: windows, scala, command-line

I have shutdown hook in my scala program and it works fine when exiting with ctrl+c, but is there some way to still perform some action after user just exits the command line window as shutdown is not called this way?

Comment: You could probably create a second process at startup that is regularly checking whether the original process is still running, and perform your special shutdown if it discovers the other application has been shut down. There's probably no way to achieve this with a single process. At least I assume that closing the terminal kills the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can hardly imagine that you can guarantee that a resource is cleaned up, no matter what. There are so many reasons for your application to terminate: Regular termination, Exceptional termination, a user stopping the process, your machine dieing, ...

However, you can build a variety of safety nets: As you did, a shutdown-handler can be defined to cleanup resources if your application is halted. Now, if you want to make sure that some resources are cleaned up, even if the entire process stops running, then you can create a second process with the sole purpose of checking whether your application is still running, and if it isn't, cleans up the resources.

Now this requires the two processes to communicate at least minimal: One process needs to know whether the other process is still running or not.

There are multiple ways to communicate. Depending on how complex you want your design to be, some are more suited. I can think of the following ways to communicate:

- Let one process build your application. This process will be the parent of the other and can check whether the other is still running
- Let the processes communicate using Remote Procedure Call (RMI). You can define an interface with a method `ping` that returns a `pong`, allowing one process to check whether the other is still alive.
- On a lower level than RMI would be a similar communication using Sockets.
- The processes could communicate over the filesystem, i.e., one process pings the other by writing a file, if the other does not react as to agreement, the process cleans up the resources. This is probably less reliable than the former methods, and probably also slower, though I have no data to support my intuition.

I am no expert, so there are surely many alternatives.

You could try doing something like this:

```
package application

import java.io._
import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

object Bootstrap {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val workingDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("newTemp")
    println("Working Directory: " + workingDirectory)
    val processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "/path/to/process.jar", workingDirectory.toAbsolutePath.toString)
    processBuilder.directory(workingDirectory.toFile)
    val process = processBuilder.start()
    new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream, "ERROR").start()
    new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream, "OUTPUT").start()
    process.waitFor()
    println("Process stopped working")
    cleanup(workingDirectory)
  }

  def cleanup(workingDirectory: Path): Unit = {
    Files.walkFileTree(workingDirectory, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path]{
      override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes): FileVisitResult = {
        Files.deleteIfExists(file)
        super.visitFile(file, attrs)
      }

      override def postVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exc: IOException): FileVisitResult = {
        Files.deleteIfExists(dir)
        super.postVisitDirectory(dir, exc)
      }
    })
  }
}

class StreamGobbler(is: InputStream, `type`: String) extends Thread {

  override def run(): Unit = {
    val isr = new InputStreamReader(is)
    val br = new BufferedReader(isr)
    var line = br.readLine()
    while (line != null){
      System.out.println(`type` + "> " + line)
      line = br.readLine()
    }
  }
}

object Process {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val workingDirectory = Paths.get(args(0))
    Files.createTempFile(workingDirectory, "Resource", ".txt")
    for(i <- 1 to 8) {
      println("Process is running")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    println("Suppose the process got killed here")
  }
}
```

To run this, create an executable jar with `Process` being the entry point, update the `"path/to/process.jar"` and run `Bootstrap`. The resource should still be cleaned up, even if you terminate the invoked child process.

I've taken the `StreamGobbler` from [ProcessBuilder: Forwarding stdout and stderr of started processes without blocking the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki), only translating it from Java to Scala.

Note that, again, if your `Bootstrap` process is killed, then your resources won't get cleaned up. Depending on how essential it is that the cleanup is done, you can either

- Create multiple independent cleanup processes that function without a master (i.e., let the parent process only create multiple cleanup processes, that communicate (e.g., over RMI) to coordinate cleanup independently on whether the parent is still running or not)
- Create multiple independent cleanup processes on different Machines, that communicate over a network. This would let you cleanup even if there is a local power outrage.

Keep in mind that, in order to minimize the risk of your application not properly cleaning up, your cleanup will become more complex. There may also be existing solutions (maybe an application server will do something like this for you?), but the existing solutions may, in return, force dependencies on you that you do not want.