# The output of linux command is not captured in java

Tags: java, linux, git, process

I am trying to run the below command from java and want to capture the output. The method is getting completed immediately without writing anything to the console.

Linux Command is `repo forall -c 'echo pwd is;pwd;git status'`
and the method is

```
public static String executeCommandWithOutput(String command) {
    System.out.println("Running the command "+command);
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    try {
        Process process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Content is "+output.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

I tried redirecting the output to a file as well. Neither worked. Any thoughts??

Comment: this link might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki

Comment: If you call `waitFor` first, the process will finish and there won't be any output to read.  Call `waitFor` *after* you've read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the command your are trying to execute has a standard output.

Probably its failing and you are getting error output.

You can check the error output with `getErrorStream`, documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29).

E.g. like this

```
StringBuffer error = new StringBuffer();

BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
        error.append(line);
}

System.out.println("Error is " + error.toString());
```

Also check the `exitValue` of your forked command, doc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29)

```
int exitStatus = process.exitValue();

System.out.println("Exit status is " + exitStatus );
```

Comment: yes.. It is throwing the error 'echo: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'''. But when i run the same command from linux terminal it is executing!