# switch user in Process Builder

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I want to switch user and then launch a command under the new user.
Actually my code is

```
String[] commandToRun2 = {"su","-","jboss", "./jboss-cli.sh -c :shutdown(restart=true)"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandToRun2);
pb.directory(new File("/home/jboss/soft/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

but I can't make it work.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Is there an Exception in the logs?

Comment: No exception, It just end the process normally but without execute correctly the command. Using the same command under root (without su) it works fine.

Comment: Did you test your `su` command manually? Do you launch your java application from the same user as you tested `su`?

Comment: yes I did. I have 2 Jboss instances, 1 under "root" user and another under "jboss" user. I need to use "su" command to launch the application under jboss.

Comment: What if you `Thread.sleep` for 1 minute to give the created process some time?

Comment: Also, try to split your problem into simpler parts. Try to execute `touch /home/jboss/testFile` first. Manually and from inside the java app that is launched from root. If it succeeds, try `su - jboss touch /home/jboss/testFile`. Find out which step starts to fail.

Comment: // `Thread.sleep(60000L)` is meant to be inserted after `pb.start()`.

Comment: @Jebus how did you managed to provide the password for that user from java code?

Comment: The user hadn't password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/777349/), your call to `su` doesn't appear to be quite right.

From that question, the `su` command should have the form

```
su [username] -c "[command]"
```

So, try the following instead:

```
String[] commandToRun2 = {"su", "jboss", "-c", "./jboss-cli.sh -c :shutdown(restart=true)"};
```

Incidentally, it may be helpful to log any output written to the process's standard output and standard error.  If there's an error, you'll then be able to see what the error is, and if the process generates a lot of output, reading the output will prevent output buffers from filling and blocking the process.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168097/) demonstrates how you can do this.

Comment: how do I provide password for the user through java code?

Comment: @HyperioN OP is executing as superuser hence there is no need to give the password.