# Communication between Java and Python through stdout

Tags: java, python

I have a Java code calling Python through an asynchronous process, and I want the Python process to listen to `stdout` from Java until something printed.

Following is the java code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class host {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("java starts at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","a.py");
        Process tr = pb.start();
        System.out.println("First msg");
        System.out.println("Second msg");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("x");
        System.out.println("java ends at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
    }
}
```

and following is the python code:

```
import sys
import time
if __name__=="__main__":
    fo=open("a.txt","w")
    fo.write('python starts at: %.0f\n'%(time.time()*1000))
    line = sys.stdout.readline()
    while(line != "x\n"):
        fo.write(line+"\n")
        line = sys.stdout.readline()
    fo.write('python ends at: %.0f\n'%(time.time()*1000))
    fo.close()
```

However, the Python process seemed not be able to capture the `stdout` from Java. Since I am new to Java, I am not sure whether there is something fundamentally wrong or not, and whether the above model provides an effective way between Java and Python communication.

**EDIT (UPDATE)**

Based on the answers/comments, I modified my Java code as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

public class host {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("java starts at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","a.py");
        Process tr = pb.start();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(tr.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("First msg"); ps.flush();
        ps.println("Second msg"); ps.flush();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        ps.println("x"); ps.flush();
        System.out.println("java ends at " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
    }
}
```

and changed python script as follows:

```
import sys
import time
if __name__=="__main__":
    fo=open("a.txt","w")
    fo.write('python starts at: %.0f\n'%(time.time()*1000))
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    while(line != "x\n"):
        fo.write(line+"\n")
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
    fo.write('python ends at: %.0f\n'%(time.time()*1000))
    fo.close()
```

And following is the output:

```
python starts at: 1453263858103
First msg

First msg

Second msg

python ends at: 1453263863103
```

Comment: Have you tinkered with redirect? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html

Comment: Your ProcessBuilder and the new runtime environment it creates when starting python has its own in, out and err streams. They are different from the Syste.in/out/err. Use the ProcessBuilder.redirectInput().

Comment: @ JayC667 That's what I thought also, but how do I pass Java stdout to python?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki as a simple example

Comment: you can't *read* from stdout. you read from stdin.

Comment: inheritIO does not do what you want. it just means that python can read form the same stdin as java. They will be parallel (but you want serial).

Comment: what you need to do is write to the output stream of the process you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, write to the process you created:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","a.py");
Process tr = pb.start();
tr.getOutputStream().println("First msg");
```

In python, read from `stdin`:

```
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: I edit my script as you suggestions with minor modifications, but still have problem (see the question)

Comment: there isn't even the first and last lines? ("python starts/ends"?)

Comment: Sorry I missed that: what do you mean by "python starts/ends"?

Comment: those lines you write at the begining and the end of your file?

Comment: I had to kill python before the output text file is getting really huge.

Comment: I think I found why. I need to flush the PrintStream.

Answer (score 2):

The receiving process should listen to stdin, not stdout.

Then pipe the output from java to python:

java -jar myjava.jar | python mylistener