# Logging InputStream

Tags: java, android, logging, inputstream

I create an InputStream class, that extends CiphetInputStream. I want to log all data from my InputStream (that i use as input in parser further) so i done following:

```
public class MyInputStream extends CipherInputStream {
    private OutputStream logStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
.....
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int read = super.read();
        logStream.write(read);
        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int read = super.read(b, off, len);
        if (read > 0) {
            logStream.write(b, off, read);
        }
        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        int read = super.read(buffer);
        if (read()>0) {
            logStream.write(buffer);
        }
        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        log();
        super.close();
    }

    public void log() {
        String logStr = new String(((ByteArrayOutputStream) logStream).toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        Log.d(getClass(), logStr);
        try {
            logStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In actual my stream has something like this:

```
<response>
<result>0</result>
</response>
```

but log show smth like this *mutation* :

```
<<response>
<resultt >0</resullt>
</respoonse>
[and (?) symbol at the end]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: maybe this solution may be helpful for somebody: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2013/12/redirect-stream-to-logcat.html

Answer (score 3):

You can combine [`TeeInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) and [`Logger.stream()`](http://log.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.17/com/jcabi/log/Logger.html#stream%28java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
new TeeInputStream(
  yourStream, 
  Logger.stream(Level.INFO, this)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see log in logcat, try `Log.i(String tag, String message);` or `System.out.println("");`. Both of them works. You can also use, `Log.d`, `Log.w` and `Log.e` also.