# How to log JSON deserialization in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, inputstream

I have a piece of code that is reading JSON data from an input stream and converting it to POJOs (using Jackson).  Sometimes, the data will fail to deserialize and it's difficult to troubleshoot.  What would be a good mechanism to see the line-by-line input stream in log4j?  Are there other tools/techniques that can help the troubleshooting?

Comment: some code involved? input stream is file? web page?

Comment: input stream is S3 bucket, but that's not relevant because it could be anything in the future.

Comment: any relevant piece of code? In java may be Decorator pattern can help you http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/cases/uw/decorator.htm

Comment: What's the exception you're getting from Jackson? Are you logging that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are already logging the exceptions and stacktraces that you are getting, and that they are not providing enough context to track down the problems.

Jackson doesn't have any internal logging that you could "tap into".

So to log the JSON input line by line, you will need to write (or find) an `InputStream` or `Reader` that wraps your source `InputStream` or `Reader` and logs each line that is read.   Here are a couple of examples that you may be able to use:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955334/139985
- [Logging everything that goes through an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907781)