# Logging everything that goes through an InputStream

Tags: java, json, gson, inputstream

I'm using Gson to process a Json response. Sometimes I get an exception but unfortunately I don't get enough context to pinpoint the exact location of the problem.

The JsonReader is created as following:

```
private JsonReader getJsonReader(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException {
    final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return new JsonReader(reader);
}
```

My idea is to subclass `InputStreamReader` and to log everything that goes through it in order to have more context when an exception is thrown.

Is there a better way?

Comment: "Better" is a very fuzzy term. I think your idea is reasonable: it should be rather easy to implement; and not require any "dramatic" changes to your code base.

Comment: The exception should normally contain sufficient context (Jackson exceptions certainly have never disappointed me in that regard).  It will depend on the framework I guess.  Subclassing `InputStream` or simply using the debugger should work to pin-point the problem.

Comment: 1) `JsonReader.toString()` outputs the current parsing location. Is it a good context? 2) I'd subclass `JsonReader`, if necessary, rather than `InputStreamReader`: `JsonReader` peels off redundant tokens by design. (Suppose a pretty-printed/formatted input stream that would have logged every whitespace, whilst decorated `JsonReader` would log JSON tokens only).

Comment: @Roland Well, it depends on what you expect a context to be. :) I thought of subclassing a `Reader` as well (but not `InputStreamReader` actually in favor of decorating), but since you're focused more on Gson stuff, I'd implement something like a subclass of `JsonReader` with a short queue of last tokens probably with their respective values. Yep, it's slightly harder to implement, but it definitely could peel of whitespaces, etc. However, you might also want to track the position (bytes read totally) in your `LoggingReader` to be more accurate on locating invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following two subclasses:

```
public class LoggingReader extends InputStreamReader {

    private char[] lastRead;

    public LoggingReader(final InputStream inputStream, final Charset charset) {
        super(inputStream, charset);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final char[] chars, final int i, final int i1) throws IOException {
        final int result = super.read(chars, i, i1);
        lastRead = chars;
        return result;
    }

    public String getLastRead() {
        return new String(lastRead);
    }
}

public class LoggingJsonReader extends JsonReader {
    private final LoggingReader reader;
    public LoggingJsonReader(final LoggingReader in) {
        super(in);
        this.reader = in;
    }

    public String getLastRead() {
        return reader.getLastRead();
    }
}
```

Now when an Exception is thrown I do:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  if (reader instanceof LoggingJsonReader) {
    LoggingJsonReader lReader = (LoggingJsonReader) reader;
    log.error(lReader.getLastRead());
  }
```